# Heroku: Installing SSL certs which need a dedicated IP

Tags: heroku

I need to install [VeriSign SSL certs](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/verisign-ssl-certificates/secure-site.aspx) on a Heroku app.

The requirements for using these certs are:

- Dedicated IP address.
- A CSR generated on the web server with the domain name.

Is it possible to achieve the above, either directly through the Heroku platform or via custom addons.

Comment: This is documented on heroku's devcenter : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the [Heroku SSL Endpoint Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint). Don't worry about the IP address, it comes courtesy of the Heroku SSL endpoint. I also don't think you need to create the certificate signing request on the server, once the certificate is created, you can use it where you want.